# No me esta funcionando mi ajax correctamente mi alert

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

este es mi ajax lo que no me funciona como quiero es mi alert donde quiero me muestre cuando me de el error un msj con el dato que se repite cuando inserto mis datos desde una tabla de excel el problema es que no se como hacerlo lo e intentado de varias formas y no puedo ahorita probe asi   alert('error; ' + eval(data)); pero no me funciona me tira un objeto como msj

```
$(document).on("submit",".formarchivo",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var nombreform=$(this).attr("id");
    var formData = new FormData($("#"+nombreform+"")[0]);
    $.ajax({
            url: 'cargar_datos_usuarios',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $(".loading").show();
                setTimeout(function() { $(".loading").show(); },3000);
            },
            success: function (data){
                alert("Se cargo con exito");
            },
            error: function (data){
                alert('error; ' + eval(data));
            },

        });
});
```

y aqui inserto mis datos

```
public function cargar_datos_usuarios(Request $request)
    {
        ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
        \DB::beginTransaction();
        $archivo = $request->file('archivo');
        $nombre_original = $archivo->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $extension = $archivo->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $rl = Storage::disk('archivos')->put($nombre_original, \File::get($archivo));
        $ruta = storage_path('archivos') . "/" . $nombre_original;


        if ($rl) {
            Excel::selectSheetsByIndex(0)->load($ruta, function ($hoja) {

                $hoja->each(function ($fila) {
                    $empleadoidentidad = empleado::where('identidad', 'like', $fila->identidad)->count();
                    if (strcmp($empleadoidentidad, $empleadoidentidad) === 0) {
                        $empleados = new empleado();
                        $empleados->nombre = $fila->nombre;
                        $empleados->identidad = $fila->identidad;
                        $empleados->num_empleado = $fila->num_empleado;
                        $empleados->fecha_nacimiento = $fila->fecha_nacimiento;
                        $empleados->direccion = $fila->direccion;
                        $empleados->telefono = $fila->telefono;
                        $empleados->celular = $fila->celular;
                        $empleados->nacionalidad = $fila->nacionalidad;
                        $empleados->correo = $fila->correo;
                        $empleados->nivel_academico = $fila->nivel_academico;
                        $empleados->titulo_obtenido = $fila->titulo_obtenido;
                        $empleados->rtn = $fila->rtn;
                        $empleados->ihss = $fila->ihss;
                        $empleados->certificado_seguro = $fila->certificado_seguro;
                        $empleados->genero = $fila->genero;
                        $empleados->estado_civil = $fila->estado_civil;
                        $empleados->departamento = $fila->departamento;
                        $empleados->municipio = $fila->municipio;
                        $empleados->tipo_contratacion = $fila->tipo_contratacion;
                        $empleados->ano_contratacion = $fila->ano_contratacion;
                        $empleados->gerencia = $fila->gerencia;
                        $empleados->unidad_ejecutora = $fila->unidad_ejecutora;
                        $empleados->actividad_obra = $fila->actividad_obra;
                        $empleados->puesto = $fila->puesto;
                        $empleados->dept_icf = $fila->dept_icf;
                        $empleados->banco = $fila->banco;
                        $empleados->no_cuenta = $fila->no_cuenta;
                        $empleados->pin = $fila->pin;
                        $empleados->vigencia = $fila->vigencia;
                        $empleados->no_contrato = $fila->no_contrato;
                        $empleados->sueldo = $fila->sueldo;
                        $empleados->sindicato = $fila->sindicato;
                        $empleados->lugar_nacimiento = $fila->lugar_nacimiento;
                        $empleados->descripcion_funciones = $fila->descripcion_funciones;
                        $empleados->forma_pago = $fila->forma_pago;
                        $empleados->lugar_recibe_pago = $fila->lugar_recibe_pago;
                        $empleados->estado_empleado = $fila->estado_empleado;
                        $empleados->save();
                        \DB::commit();
                    }
                });
            });
            return view("vista_exel.importar_datos_exel")->with("msj", "Usuarios cargados con exito");
        } else {
            return view("vista_exel.importar_datos_exel")->with("msj", "Error al subir archivo");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hola! Revisaste el inspector del navegador, en la pestaña **red** o **network** depende del browser. Para ver si se ejecuta la llamada Ajax, puede que este fallando la ruta, o este mal declarada, toma nota de los errores http que genera (ejemplo 404,4xx, pueden brindarte info adicional)

Comment: Revisa si el nombre de la ruta 'cargar_datos_usuarios' coincide con el nombre del archivo .php. Hace bastante que no manejo php puro, pero te paso un enlace capa te es util. https://www.imaginanet.com/blog/usando-ajax-un-simple-ejemplo-con-php-y-jquery.html

Comment: si la ruta si me funciona inclusivamente me muesta el error en el navegar de 500 el cual me muestra el dato que estoy duplicando por que en mi base le tengo unico

Comment: pero no se como mostrarlo en el alert

Answer (score 0):

Para mostrar un mensaje de error del tipo *Usuario duplicado* porque el servidor te da un error 500, podrias incorporar lo siguiente en el callback de *error()* de tu *ajax*

```
error: function (xhr, status, error){
            if(xhr.status == 500) {
              alert('Usuario duplicado');
             }
        },
```

Podrias dar info del error en el alert() como sigue:

```
alert('Usuario duplicado Error' + xhr.responseText);
```

Tambien podrias agregar info sobre que usuario esta duplicado, accediendo a un input donde tengas guardado el dato, sea apellido, nombre, etc.
Esto lo puedes resolver con javascript o jquery

```
// en javascript
   var usuario = document.getElementById('id de tu input').value;
   alert('Usuario duplicado: ' + usuario);
// en jquery
   var usuario = $("#id de tu input).val();
   alert('Usuario duplicado: ' + usuario);
```

Recuerda que en tu template, tienes que tener declarado el *id* de tus inputs, select, checkbox, etc.

Te dejo un par de enlaces:[Manejo de errores en Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637019/how-to-get-the-jquery-ajax-error-response-text) [Otro posteo en stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637019/how-to-get-the-jquery-ajax-error-response-text)

Tal vez, te convendra usar manejo de exepciones en tu archivo php con *try() { } catch() { }* , te copio la documentación [exepciones php puro](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.exceptions.php)

Comment: si me funciona me muesta el usuario duplicado pero como podria mostrar el dato del usuario que esta duplicado o como concatenarle el msj del error estuve viendo los ejemplos pero no lo puedo lograr

Comment: es que no e trabajado mucho con ajax y de esta forma por eso tanto se me complica

Comment: La intención de mostrar usuario duplicado no es para nada lo mismo que la naturaleza de un error 500 que indica errores de programación del lado del servidor

Comment: Pudiste resolverlo? Tuviste algún avance?